# retrieving data from twitter python

Tags: python, twitter

I am trying to build an app where users will be able to connect to my app, enter a keyword for searching on twitter and then the results will be stored on a database. From the moment the user enters a keyword I want to keep track of what is being said on twitter.Those results will be further analyzed and some statistics will be presented to the user. 
So far I have used tweppy and twitter streaming api for getting the tweets. But I realized that I can not have more than one open streaming connections (for searching in parallel for multiple keywords).
I searched the stackoverflow and found solutions like disconnect, connect and then search with a new keyword, but in that case I am going to lose data.

Also I checked the Twitter API, which gives you 450 results max/15 min:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/1.1/limits

Stream API:
- public stream doesn't give the oppurtunity to have  more than connections
- Site stream doesn't give you the oppurtunity for search

Firehose API is not option since is too expensive.

How can I solve this problem? I am seeing many apps searching live for more instances than one. Have anyone met this before?

Answer (score 0):

You could use tweepy to collect all tweets from the sample or filter streaming endpoint and save this to a database. Then use the database to only return tweets for your search term.

If you don't want tweets to persist for too long, you might have better results using noSQL databases like redis and using an expiration timestamp, so it doesn't fill up infinitely.

Comment: Sample and filter only returns a certain amount of tweets and unless the user defined keyword is trend probably will not included in the results so my data will be useless for someone searching something very specific.